# File wc-template-functions.php in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter, woocommerce

I am trying to change something in my wc-template-functions.php file. I made a copy and put it into my child-theme/woocommerce/includes folder. But it seems to be the wrong way.

The seecond way I tried is via the functions.php file. But this is not working too. Is there something wrong in my code?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_template_loop_category_title',  'artwood_home_category_title');
function artwood_home_category_title( $category ) {
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_title' ) ) {
?>
            <div class="woocommerce-loop-category-text">               
    <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">

                    <?php
            echo $category->name;

            if ( $category->count > 0 ) {
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );
            }
        ?>
    </h2>
            </div>
    <?php
}
}
```

I just want to add the class

```
<div class="woocommerce-loop-category-text">
```

before `<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">`

Is my filter wrong in some parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to remove the default Woo-commerce hook `woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title` using `remove_action()`

After remove default Woo-Commerce hook add new action hook `woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title` with your custom function like below using `add_action()`

Below code goes to theme's `function.php` file

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'custom_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10 );
function custom_woocommerce_template_loop_category_title( $category ) {
    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-loop-category-text">
        <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">
            <?php
                echo $category->name;

                if ( $category->count > 0 ) {
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', ' <mark class="count">(' . $category->count . ')</mark>', $category );
                }
            ?>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, this worked without any problems ;)